# Удаление UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf

Как удалить динамически созданный контрол?
Присваивание его к `null` не помогает.

```
Rectangle lol = new Rectangle { Width = 20, Height = 20 };
canvas.Children.Add(lol);
// Много кода ...
lol = null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы должны удалить его из его контейнера:

```
canvas.Children.Remove(lol);
```

Обнуление ссылки на контрол лишь просто теряет саму ссылку, контрол при этом никуда не исчезает.

---

Вообще, этот принцип работает во всём C#: в переменных содержатся не объекты, а лишь ссылки на них*, поэтому обнуление ссылки не убьёт объект. Вообще, объекты умрут сами (будут съедены уборщиком мусора), когда на них больше *ни у кого* не останется ссылок (да и то не сразу, а когда-нибудь потом). В вашем случае на ваш объект `Rectangle` оставалась ссылка у контейнера.

*<sub>за исключением типов-значений, да</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Внезапно:

```
canvas.Children.Remove(lol);
```

А своим кодом вы только меняете значение переменной.