# Почему не удаляется элемент из List?

Tags: c#

Почему не удаляется элемент из List?

```
    class lol
    {
        public int id;
        public int a = 0;
        public int b = 0;
    }
    static int counter = 0;
    static List<lol> myarray = new List<lol>();

    static lol returnbyid(List<lol> lst, int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (myarray[i].id == id)
            {
                return myarray[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            lol tmp = new lol();
            tmp.id = ++counter;
            tmp.a = rand.Next();
            tmp.b = rand.Next();
            myarray.Add(tmp);
        }
        lol ret = returnbyid(myarray, 3);
        ret = null; // Вот тут я хотел удалить элемент
    }
```

Comment: Не вижу в вашем коде удаления из коллекции. Используйте, например, метод [`List<T>.Remove`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) для удаления элементов из коллекции.

Comment: _"ret = null; // Вот тут я хотел удалить элемент"_ -- обнуление - это не удаление. недавно же было объяснение -- [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480127/196972)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что обнуление ссылки на объект ничего с самим объектом не делает. И уж точно не превращает его в `null` или в «ничего».

Ссылка — не сам объект, а лишь что-то, что *ссылается* на него.

```
                 ----------         коллекция    ---------------------
           /--->|  объект  |<--\      [ 0 ]---->| ещё какой-то объект |
          /      ----------     \     [ 1 ]      ---------------------
ret -----/                       \    [ 2 ]
                                  \---[ 3 ]
```

Когда вы обнуляете ссылку, вы просто обнуляете ссылку, объект от этого не меняется:

```
                 ----------         коллекция    ---------------------
                |  объект  |<--\      [ 0 ]---->| ещё какой-то объект |
                 ----------     \     [ 1 ]      ---------------------
ret -> ∅                         \    [ 2 ]
                                  \---[ 3 ]
```

Для того, чтобы удалить объект из списка, вы должны попросить список сделать это для вас (`myarray.Remove(ret)`). Методов «уничтожить» объект в C# просто нет (окей, есть сборщик мусора, но и он не даёт никаких гарантий).

Comment: _"ret -> X"_ -- лучше так `ret -> null`

Comment: @Stack: Хм. Получится, что `ret` _указывает_ на `null`, а он на деле _является_ `null`'ом.

Comment: @Stack: Нужен какой-то хитрый символ, с которым понятно, что это _ничего_.

Comment: X в коробочке - это для начинающих менее понятно чем null. т.к. null встречается в коде, а X в коробочке - нет. _"Нужен какой-то хитрый символ"_ -- есть [null symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_symbol)

Comment: @Stack: А так ?

Comment: _"А так ?"_ -- хорошо. можно еще добавить (␀)

Comment: @Stack: У меня выглядит странно: http://i.stack.imgur.com/E8aWU.png А у вас?

Comment: я с wikipedia копировал из строки: `Null character, U+0000, (␀), U+2400 "symbol for null", a single-character glyph "NUL"` -- выглядит как (nul).

Comment: @Stack: У меня FF и IE на Win7 показывают странно. Оставлю пока так, если будут вопросы, отвечу словами.

Answer (score 2):

Единственно верный ответ: потому что вы его нигде не удаляете.
Подробнее: для удаления элементов из коллекции `List<T>` следует использовать один из методов:

- [`List<T>.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`List<T>.RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`List<T>.RemoveRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y33yd2b5(v=vs.110).aspx)

В вашем случае прекрасно подойдет первый метод:

```
myarray.Remove(ret);
```